# Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'MyFirstProject'. java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed recently Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
Build id: 20190314-1200

When I create a project I receive the following error:

[image]

---

'Building workspace' has encountered a problem. Errors occurred during the build.

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'MyFirstProject'.
java.lang.NullPointerException

---

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved by installing an older eclipse version (eclipse-java-2018-12-R).

it looks like its a bug in the new release.

To whoever face this issue in the future, I am using windows 10, 64 bit, home edition. and the eclipse version I have faced the issue with is Eclipse IDE 2019‑03

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that eclipse was installed correctly, I encountered this error when I first installed it.

The issue for me was that the installer had not completley finished and encountered an error, so have a go at uninstalling and reinstalling and make sure that no websites come up saying that the jdk or jre are not installed.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled Eclipse, but still the same error.

Comment: did you make sure that no website popped up saying that something was not installed?

Comment: Again I uninstalled the eclipse and deleted the workspace. when I created a project I received a new error: Building workspace, Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'MyFirstProject'.
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Do you have to use Eclipse at all? Why not try NetBeans?

Comment: I am following a training course for java and the trainer is using eclipse. it would be much easier for me to go with whatever the trainer is using

Comment: I see. Can you create a simple Java program with "Hello, world!", save it as Test.java and try compiling from the command line with:
javac test.java
?

Comment: @khayat first I would make sure that eclipse is up to date - help >> check for updates second, I would try restarting your computer to make sure that all is installed correctly..

Comment: @danwillm, I checked and it's up to date. I restarted my laptop but still the same issue

Comment: @LuisDipak, I did create Hello, world as following: /* This is a simple Java program. 
   FileName : "HelloWorld.java". */
class HelloWorld 
{ 
    // Your program begins with a call to main(). 
    // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window. 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Hello, World"); 
    } 
}, I run it as you suggested no errors received but I didn't receive the output as well.

Comment: Ok, that means that your code is compiling with no errors. that's good.
If look in the folder, you now have a file called: HelloWorld.class
This .class file is the executable file
To see your output, just run it like this:
java HelloWorld

Comment: If you can see the output, that means, the compiler "javac" and the "java" program are both in your PATH.

Comment: If all goes well, next I would recommend tge above suggestion on rebooting your computer, since you're on Windows.

Comment: @LuisDipak, I run the program using java and I can see the output. rebooting my computer didn't solve the issue unfortunately

Comment: Just use NetBeans which is very good for beginners and later you will be able to sort the Eclipse issue.